# Send more than one attribute for the request.setAttribute ()

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee

I am developing a web page where on the homepage (in my case it is my "Home" servlet) I wish to present information about several tables as well as queries to them. What I have achieved is to obtain the information of my company / brands table and show the last companies added, the detail is that I do not know how to send more than one attribute for the request.setAttribute () since I want to show in my homepage information of my users table and show my featured users as well as my table news show the last post (news from suppliers). I hope and I can help myself since I am super stuck with this.

This is my code for my servlet.

```
 public class InicioController extends HttpServlet {
       @Override
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            RequestDispatcher rd;
            //Connection DB
            conexion conn = new conexion();
            //send objectd  Connection to the constructor of myDAO class
            HomeDAO fun = new HomeDAO(conn);
            List<companies> list1 = new LinkedList<>();
            List<users> list2 = new LinkedList<>();
            List<postNews> list3 = new LinkedList<>();
            // call to the method that gets the information from my companies table
            list1=fun.ShowCompanies("");
            // call to the method that gets the information from my Users table
            list2=fun.LastUsers("");
            // call to the method that gets the information from my Posts table
            list3=fun.News("");
            //disconnect DB
            conn.desconectar();
            //how to send more than one attribute "request.setAttribute ()"
            request.setAttribute("Companies", list1);
            rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just call the method again with another attribute name and another object.

Comment: like that? request.setAttribute("attribute2 ", object2); and request.setAttribute("attribute3 ", object3);

Comment: Yeah, think of the attributes as a map. You'll have to use the same string key to retrieve the attributes later.

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you have an object that will contain all three lists, plus whatever other objects you want to "pass" to your JSP? Your attribute will contain that single object in an attribute and the JSP can sort it out. It's good design also, because that way you have in one class, all the "parameters" that the specific JSP expects.